# SSL for a WFE in SharePoint FARM

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssl, wfe

In a SharePoint FARM CSR is generated form one WFE, cant it be installed all the WFE`s?

a fresh CSR has to be generated for every WFE in SP FARM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the following.

- Create CSR from One Server
- Complete the cert request on the same server
- Now export the SSL cert from here
- Import it on all other servers(wfe).

If you create the CSR from all servers then SSL will be different on each server.